# Spark RDD Sampling, faster with or without replacement?

Tags: apache-spark

In general, all other things being equal, which would be expected to run more quickly?

```
val a = myRDD.sample(true,  0.01)
val b = myRDD.sample(false, 0.01)
```

Comment: this feels like a trick question :D is there not any bench mark test result?

Comment: I assumed the answer would be easy to find; so I ask here hoping for a canonical answer.